TailwindCSS Breakpoints aren't applying
I have a NextJS 14 project that I am using Tailwind CSS with. I have the following:
<div className="text-amber-dim md:text-amber flex-1 h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
   <div className="absolute z-[1] cursor-default">
    <CubeAnimation size={140} />
  </div>
</div>

Additionally, the classes:
* Class for amber text */
.text-amber {
  color: rgb(var(--amber));
  background-color: rgb(var(--background-rgb));
}

/* Class for amber text but dimmer */
.text-amber-dim {
  color: rgba(var(--amber-dim));
}

The brighter color class is prefixed with md, but doesn't apply where it should. It is supposed to apply .text-amber on displays >640px in width, but never applies on any width.
Looking at Tailwind's documentation the responsive design page notes that Tailwind CSS operates a mobile-first breakpoint system, meaning unprefixed utilities are applied on all platforms, and prefixed utilities take effect at the breakpoint and above. However, I tested the code in a window >640px and the colors did not change.
I checked my overrides, which I have none, I also tried adding more content directories which didn't work. Additionally, I verified that the tags make it past hydration:
<div class="text-amber-dim md:text-amber flex-1 h-screen flex items-center justify-center"></div>

The child of the <div> is a <pre> tag if that changes anything. I tried to move the color tags onto the <pre> tag but that also didn't work.

This question is similar to: Tailwindcss how to use custom classes with responsive variants. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Use @layer to enable modifier features with custom classes.

It seems you may have meant to write a comment "Class for amber text" but missed out a preceding slash /:
/* Class for amber text */

Your potential mistype version:
* Class for amber text */

May be causing negative effects to the selector of the rule.
Furthermore, only classes "known" by Tailwind can be modified with variants like md:. To make custom classes known to Tailwind, ensure they are in a @layer base/components/utilities, as per the documentation (emphasis mine):

For more power, you can also use the @layer directive to add styles to Tailwind’s base, components, and utilities layers:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .my-custom-style {
    /* ... */
  }
}

The @layer directive helps you control declaration order by automatically relocating your styles to the corresponding @tailwind directive, and also enables features like modifiers and tree-shaking for your own custom CSS.

Thus, it would seem most appropriate to wrap your custom rules in @layer utilities:
@layer utilities {
  /* Class for amber text */
  .text-amber {
    color: rgb(var(--amber));
    background-color: rgb(var(--background-rgb));
  }

  /* Class for amber text but dimmer */
  .text-amber-dim {
    color: rgba(var(--amber-dim));
  }
}


Thanks! I added the classes to the utilities and it works perfectly now.
